# Number of combinations in a 4 digit code with rules

Tags: combinations

I am sure there is a general and simplified way to solve this problem, I am just unable to figure out the generalized formula (if there is one).

Say we have to write a **code with 4 digits**, the digits can range from **0** to **9**.

All digits in the code **must be unique**.
All of the digits cannot be **neither increasing nor decreasing**.

For example, "1234" is not allowed, neither is "1289" nor "9821".

How many code combinations are there in total?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The total number of combinations is $\binom{10}{4}$.

For each combination there are $4!$ different arrangements.

Exactly $1$ of these arrangements is strictly increasing.

Exactly $1$ of these arrangements is strictly decreasing.

Hence the number of valid arrangements is $\binom{10}{4}\cdot(4!-1-1)$.

Comment: @amWhy: Not sure I understand your reasoning. First I choose $4$ distinct digits. For each choice, I have $24$ arrangements, and since the digits are distinct, there are only $2$ strict-direction arrangements.

Comment: @amWhy: If you are unable to explain your reasoning, then I'd appreciate it if you could revoke your down-vote.

Comment: Yes, I think you've got it; I was coming at it from a different direction!

Comment: Barak But I did not downvote your answer! Though I can upvote it.

Comment: @amWhy: Oh, OK... Well, somebody did at around the same time you posted your comment, so I figured that it was you... Thanks.

Comment: @barakmanos Sorry I have done the downvote. Please make a small edit.

Comment: @callculus: Done, but why did you down-vote?

Comment: @barakmanos I thought you didn´t catch all combinations. But now it looks right to me.

Comment: @callculus: OK, but could you please (please) next time, post a comment explaining why. It is rather annoying to get unexplained down-votes, in particularly when you're pretty sure that you've answered everything correctly. And even if you've made a mistake which justifies the down-vote, you cannot be aware of your mistake and learn from it when no explanation is provided. Personally, I always opt for a comment rather than a down-vote (i.e., only comment, no down-vote). That's your choice of course, but down-voting without any explanation is a kinda trolling IMO.

Comment: @barakmanos You´re are right. I was formulating a comment but then I wasn´t sure anymore. But as you have seen I posted a comment to inform you that I was the downvoter. That was the best I could do after my mistake. After your edit I changed my downvote into an upvote. My intention was not to downvote and run away. I had your answer always in focus.

Comment: @callculus: cool, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint. Once you choose $4$ distinct digits in $\{0,1,\dots,9\}$ (you can do it in $\binom{10}{4}$ ways) in how many ways can you arrange them in decreasing order? How many in increasing order? Now take them away from the $4!$ possible permutations.